# Поиск по объектам JavaScript

Tags: javascript, парсер, объекты

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста решить мою задачу. У меня есть три таблицы в базе данных: Материк, Страна, Город.

Мне нужно по названию города определить страну и материк. Как я понимаю, для этого нужно перебрать Материки, Страны и Города, но я абсолютно не понимаю как это сделать, чтобы в итоге я получил три переменные с тремя id (материк, страна, город).

Вот как выглядит база данных:

```
Таблица “Материки”

id материка  , name материка
```

.

```
Таблица “Страны”

id страны , id материка , name страны
```

.

```
Таблица “Города”

id города , id страны , name города
```

Я уже получил материки из базы данных и поместил их в Объекты. Нужно чтобы алгоритм перебирал внутри каждого материка страны и внутри каждой страны города до тех пор, пока не найдет города. Когда город найден, нужно чтобы у меня были переменные с id города, материка и страны.

Сразу загружать все города будет очень долго, поэтому думаю, что перебирать поочереди будет лучше. Возможно ошибаюсь.

Я изучаю  JS, других языков не знаю, поэтому на JS нужно.

Как выглядят json:

```
{"id":1,"materik":"name"}

{"id":1,"materik_id":2,"strana":"name"}

{"id":1,"strana_id":2,"gorod":"name"}
```

Города не пересекаются, так как в каждой стране на своём языке написано название.

Можете написать код, который позволит мне по name города определить id страны и материка ? Сам не могу разобраться , на готовом примере будет куда проще вникнуть..

Comment: при чем здесь javascript?

Comment: Городов с одинаковым именем может много, в разных странах. Например - Ватерлоо.

Comment: Совсем забыл написать об этом. Мне на языке javascript нужно. Все данные у меня в json уже получены и находятся в массивах.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы сделали маленький пример этих трех массивов и добавили это в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил в основную запись.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var continents = [
  {"id":1,"materik":"Africa"},
  {"id":2,"materik":"America"}
];

var countries = [
  {"id":1,"materik_id":"2","strana":"Canada"},
  {"id":2,"materik_id":"1","strana":"Gabon"}
];

var cities = [
  {"id":1,"strana_id":"1","gorod":"Toronto"}
];



var cityName = "Toronto";

var city = cities.find(function(item){ 
  return item.gorod == cityName; 
});
if (city) {
  var country = countries.find(function(item){ 
    return item.id == city.strana_id; 
  });
  if (country) {
    var continent = continents.find(function(item){
      return item.id == country.materik_id;
    });
    
    console.log(city);
    console.log(country);
    console.log(continent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как можно реализовать тоже самое, но в обратном порядке? Городов же очень много, там более 2,5 миллионов

Comment: "в обратном порядке" - что это значит? Найти город, если дан континент?

Answer (score 0):

При правильном подходе ваши структуры данных будут иметь вид

```
var continents = {
  "1": {"materik":"Africa"},
  "2": {"materik":"America"}
};

var countries = {
  "1": {"materik_id":"2","strana":"Canada"},
  "2": {"materik_id":"1","strana":"Gabon"}
};

var cities = {
  "1": {"strana_id":"1","gorod":"Toronto"}
};
```

Далее, при правильном подходе извлечения чего-либо из данных по названию города не будет производиться. Вместо этого будет производиться извлечение по ID.

Примерно так в целом:

```
continents[countries[cities[1].strana_id].materik_id].materik
```

При еще более правильном подходе все это будет делаться на стороне базы данных, поскольку в реальном мире городов очень много, и эти данные не удастся закэшировать на клиенте, чтобы разгрузить сервер, или я не знаю, на что вы еще рассчитывали с подходом из вопроса. В принципе, это целесообразно только в том случае, если вы на сервисе на базе Node.js хотите закэшировать таблицы в памяти.